# Keep hovering tooltip image near mouse pointer in scrolling div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a span element which occurs multiple times in text which always has a child `<img>` element which acts as a hoverable image tooltip, through these styles;

```
.tooltipLink img {
  float:left;
  display:none;
}
.tooltipLink:hover img{
  display:inherit;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1000;
  overflow:hidden;
  border-radius: 13px;
}
```

where the text would be `<span className="tooltipLink">something like this<img src="linkToImg.jpg"></span>`. I've now started adding these spans to a section of my page that scrolls within itself (it's a div with `max-height:500px` and `overflow-y:scroll`), and hovering over the spans in this div gives horribly offset results downwards, usually leading to the image not being visible on the page. I've tried all sorts of `layout` keywords but nothing actually fixes the issue. It's fine when the div is scrolled all the way to the top, but start scrolling down the div to expose other spans, and the tooltip image moves progressively lower down the page until it vanishes entirely.

If I change the position to `inherit`, it at least goes near the span that triggered it, but it pushes aside the text instead of hovering over it (despite the `z-index`). That's the closest I've gotten so far.

Comment: please provide fiddle link or demo link, so that we can help you better.

Comment: does your .tooltipLink  have position:relative? https://jsfiddle.net/rhw7pn2u/ - check this

Comment: @GL.awog that solved the issue, if you make that an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does your `.tooltipLink` have `position:relative`?

```
.tooltipLink {
  position:relative;
}
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rhw7pn2u)**